# Include node_modules in Project Laravel using Webpack

Tags: node.js, laravel, webpack

I know this is a dumb question. But I have followed the tutorial in Laravel on how to include node_modules into my project. I already configured inside my

`resources/assets/js/app.js`

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));
```

and configured in my webpack.mix.js

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/testvue.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

However, when I try to run my code I always get a 
**Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined**

Is there something that I need to configure with Webpack?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure that you added require.js dependency?

Comment: @vizsatiz I think not. Can you help me? The documentation from Laravel is lacking. And It is my first time using Webpack

Comment: I have not worked on laravel yet, but I have enabled require in angular app before. So with that limited knowledge I know you should add require js to your dependencies. You can refer https://requirejs.org/docs/start.html on how to do that. If you really want it, I can explain that as an answer to this question

Comment: What version of Node and npm do you have installed? What operating system are you using? Are you getting this error in the cli or the browser?

Comment: @RossWilson Windows 10, Yes on Google Chrome's console. Node 10.2.1, NPM 5.6.0. Really don't have a clue on how to fix it.

Comment: In that case could you add your webpack.mix.js file and the HTML snippet of your script tag (so I can see the `src` for the script tag) to your question?

Comment: @RossWilson I already added my webpack.mix.js code in my question. for the HTML file it is is a simple <script src="http://localhost/testproject/public/js/app.js"  type="text/javascript" ></script>

Comment: Oh yeah sorry, I completely blanked over that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're running `mix.scripts(...)` you code won't end up being transpiled and require statements won't actually work. `scripts` is mainly used to simply concatenate and minify js files.

You should instead use `mix.js(...)`:

Change

```
mix.scripts([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/testvue.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

To

```
mix.js([
    'resources/assets/js/app.js',
    'resources/assets/js/testvue.js'
], 'public/js/app.js');
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/mix#working-with-scripts

Comment: Thank YOU!!!! it worked!! :) I thought both the mix.scripts and mix.js are the same.

Comment: @drake24 Glad I could help. Sorry I didn't notice it sooner.